# Allow Surface Pro Type Cover use when folded back

Tags: microsoft-surface-pro-4

I use a **Surface Pro 4** on my daily basis, when I'm at my desk I connect it to a 27 inch display using the **Project > Second screen only** setting. I really like to use the Type Cover (better than buy a mouse/keyboard set and use the only USB port available) so I lay down the surface fully extended on my desk and it's ready to work, but that use a lot of space, and isn't really comfortable to use or move around (isn't possible to move really, my desk is really small).

Is it possible to use the keyboard when is: 1) folded back, or 2) attached reversely? I don't get response in both cases but maybe editing the right Registry will do it. Has someone try it and succeeded? Or have any idea where start to look?

Answer (score 0):

No, the connector for the Surface Type Cover is not reversible. It is not an issue of a registry hack, it is that the connector pins are designed to match their appropriate connection points on the tablet when they are oriented properly, and when not oriented properly is it essentially unplugging the keyboard from the tablet.

Comment: Well then the first option could be possible? I mean, avoid the keyboard deactivation when it's folded back in tablet mode.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mechanism by which that disables the keyboard and don't have a Surface tablet to explore. If the disconnect is mechanical then the same problem exists. If it is a disconnect in the software, then this may be possible.